# Bootstrap css Aligns the text to the center by the text length of the other div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use css, bootstrap to align the first line align left, and the second line will center on the text length of the first line.

I tried many ways but not.[image]

code follow

```
             <div class="col-md-6">
                <a href="/" style="text-decoration:none">
                    <div class="col-md-12 row-eq-height" style="padding:0;">
                        <div class="col-md-2" style="padding:0">
                            <img src="/Content/images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-10 tex-center" style="padding-right:0;">
                            <div style="padding:0">
                                <div class="line1-bold">THIS IS THE FIRST LONG HEADLINE</div>
                                <div class="line2">THIS IS THE SECOND HEADLINE</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
```

Comment: You need to provide what you are trying to accomplish and the code you used.

Comment: Some Code Please...

Comment: thank for care, I updated my question, please review and help me solve it,

Comment: @TranAudi What about responsive mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this..

```html
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 


<div class="col-md-6">
                <a href="/" style="text-decoration:none">
                    <div class="col-md-12 row-eq-height" style="padding:0;">
                        <div class="col-xs-2" style="padding:0">
                            <img src="https://www.tenforums.com/attachments/browsers-email/18558d1485951187t-microsoft-edge-logo-microsoft-edge-100582336-large.png" class="img-responsive" style="width:100px" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="" style="float:left;">
                         <div class="line1-bold" style="color:#b63957; font-size:18px;">THIS IS THE FIRST LONG HEADLINE</div>
                                <div class="line2" style="color:#b63957; font-size:16px; text-align:center;">THIS IS THE SECOND HEADLINE</div>
                        
                        </div>
                        
                        
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?
I don't know about your task, but I deleted some tags.

CSS

```
.img-responsive {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}
span {
  display: block;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                <a href="/" style="text-decoration:none">
                    <div class="col-md-12 row-eq-height" style="padding:0;">
                            <img src="https://www.tenforums.com/attachments/browsers-email/18558d1485951187t-microsoft-edge-logo-microsoft-edge-100582336-large.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
<span class="text-left">THIS IS THE FIRST LONG HEADLINE</span>
<span class="text-center">THIS IS THE SECOND HEADLINE</span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
```

[Reference Link](http://jsfiddle.net/0dyf2d9j/)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the class `text-center` to your divs.

Here is a working [pen](https://codepen.io/robwelan/pen/rzOwxx).